# Emacs: dired plus still opens new buffer even with togle-dired-find-file-reuse-dir

Tags: emacs

In emacs 23.3.1 on ubuntu 11.10, I have dired-plus installed. In my .emacs, I have:

```
(require 'dired+)
(toggle-diredp-find-file-reuse-dir 1)
```

When I press RET on a directory then C-x C-b, the Buffer List shows that there is only one buffer in use for dired. However, after I use ^, I have two dired buffers. C-x C-b confirms that there are two buffers: one for parent dir, one for child dir.

Is there anyway to keep the reuse work for ^ ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution: using [dired-single](http://www.northbound-train.com/emacs.html#MyPackages)

Also found on [MELPA](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/dired-single), and thus can be installed via package-list-packages.

Answer (score 0):

One can also open a new directory or file in Dired, without creating a new buffer, with the key 'a' (dired-find-alternate-file).

It's a disabled command, this code enable it:

> (put 'dired-find-alternate-file 'disabled nil)